# GUI Emacs sets the exec-path only from Windows environment variable but not from .emacs file

Tags: microsoft-windows, path, gui-emacs, exec-path

I use Emacs 25.1 on my Windows XP laptop both as a command-line app (on ConEmu terminal emulator with MSYS bash as the shell) and as the GUI Emacs. I mainly use Emacs to test and compile programs, so I frequently use Mono C# compiler (gmcs) and GCC. The path of gmcs is defined inside the Windows environment variable Path, so when I use gmcs in GUI Emacs, it works.

But the path of GCC (**/c/MinGW/bin**) is defined inside **~/.bashrc**   and if I try to use GCC in GUI Emacs, it doesn't work.

If I start **emacs -nw** from within ConEmu terminal and try to compile a C code using `M-x compile & gcc my-c-code.c -o my-c-code.exe` there's no problem: Emacs recognizes the gcc command and does the compilation.

When I try to do the same thing in GUI Emacs it says:

```
gcc my-c-code.c -o my-c-code.exe
/usr/bin/bash: gcc: command not found
```

To introduce the GCC's path into Emacs's exec-path I've added these into .emacs file:

```
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("C:/MinGW/bin")))
(setenv "PATH" (concat "C:/MinGW/bin"  (getenv "PATH")))
(setq shell-file-name "C:/msys32/usr/bin/bash.exe")
```

but none of them helped. The last line helped only if I open a shell within GUI Emacs, but not at the **M-x compile** stage.

How can I define the path of GCC inside the .emacs file? Note that I might add the path of GCC in the Windows env variable Path, but I don't want to solve it that way, I'd like to solve it the Emacs way. Thank you!

Comment: I think missed a semicolon in your `setenv`, it should be `(setenv "PATH" (concat "C:/MinGW/bin;"  (getenv "PATH")))`

Comment: Hey that worked! Can't figure out why those semicolons are strictly necessary to make it work, though. More importantly, on this [SO page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740836/compiling-c-programs-with-emacs-on-windows), on the selected answer there are no semicolons.On this [page](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_env_var_paths.html) semicolons were used but I haven't noticed them. Could you please post an answer along with a note stating why semicolons are necessary in this case? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### `PATH` vs `exec-path`

The `PATH` environment variable lists directories for programs to find executable files (when executing a non-absolute filename).  The `exec-path` Emacs variable lists directories for Emacs to find executable files (again, when executing a non-absolute filename).  The value of `exec-path` takes its value from the environment variable `PATH` when starting up (hence, `PATH` does effectively tell Emacs where to find executables, just like all other programs).

#### `exec-path` is for things run directly by Emacs

> on this [SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740836/compiling-c-programs-with-emacs-on-windows), on the selected answer there are no semicolons.

That answer deals with modifying `shell-file-name`, i.e., the shell that Emacs runs.  If you use a relative file-name for `shell-file-name`, `exec-path` will be consulted, hence there is no reason to worry about path separators.

#### `PATH` is for everything else

The `compile-command` is a shell command, i.e., Emacs runs a shell and then tells that shell to run `compile-command`.  This shell inherits the `PATH` environment variable from Emacs, but of course it doesn't see `exec-path`.  Therefore, if you use a relative file-name in `compile-command`, the `PATH` environment variable will be consulted.

### Filenames in `PATH` must be (semi)colon separated

On most operating systems (i.e., all the ones that Emacs runs on), environment variables can only hold strings, so the list has to be encoded by separating the directory names with a special character.  On Windows this character is the semi-colon, on Unix-like systems it's a colon.  To write portable elisp, use the variable `path-separator` which has the right character for the current system.

---

Hence the correct answer for this question is:

```el
(setenv "PATH" (concat "C:/MinGW/bin;" (getenv "PATH")))
```

Or to make things bit neater, and keep `exec-path` and `PATH` synchronized:

```el
(add-to-list 'exec-path "C:/MinGW/bin")
(setenv "PATH" (mapconcat #'identity exec-path path-separator))
```

Comment: The neater version looks very practical and I've put it in my .emacs file. The distinction between the exec-path and the Path of Emacs is quite clear now. Thank you.