# el-get Basic Setup (https://github.com/dimitri/el-get) : error: Unable to find 'git'

Tags: microsoft-windows, git, el-get

Start Emacs from gitbash (MINGW64)

Snippet below is loaded automatically:

```
; add el-get to the load path, and install it if it doesn't exist
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/el-get/el-get")
(unless (require 'el-get nil 'noerror)
  (with-current-buffer
      (url-retrieve-synchronously
       "https://raw.github.com/dimitri/el-get/master/el-get-install.el")
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (eval-print-last-sexp)))
```

**Error:**

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading 'c:/Users/user/.emacs':
error: Unable to find 'git'

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the cause of the error in your initialization file. Start Emacs with the '--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

; add el-get to the load path, and install it if it doesn't exist
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/el-get/el-get")
(unless (require 'el-get nil 'noerror)
  (with-current-buffer
      (url-retrieve-synchronously
       "https://raw.github.com/dimitri/el-get/master/el-get-install.el")
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (eval-print-last-sexp)))

**Environments and settings:**

- Windows 10
- Git installed (git version 2.14.1.windows.1)
- Git installation path(C:\Program Files\Git\cmb) is added to Environment path variable.
- HOMEPATH: c:/Users/user
- emacs version: GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86 64-w64-mingw32) of 2018-05-30

**git can not be found even though it's installed. How can I configure Git set-up properly?**

Comment: Just to be sure: Are you sure that your `PATH` env var points to the git executable? (I know you said it does.) If not, then this question sounds like a duplicate of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/51164/105.

Comment: yes - "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\" is added to `PATH` env var. Under the cmd folder, there are application files: git; git-gui; gitk. Thank you Drew for looking at my question!

Comment: at the same time found on github that this `(setq exec-path (cons "/usr/local/git/bin/" exec-path))` may help Emacs to locate the executable. I will try to see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: added both `(setq exec-path (cons "C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/" exec-path))` and `(setq exec-path (cons "C:/Program Files/Git/bin/" exec-path))` to my ~/.emacs file but it does not help.

Comment: Thanks for checking. Hopefully someone will have a good answer.

Comment: The snippet seems to be duplicated after the error in you post, or do I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

fixed by also adding the `(setq exec-path (cons "C:/Program Files/Git/bin/" exec-path))` to another file (el-get-settings) where the snippet is actually in.

```
Cloning into 'el-get'...
POST git-upload-pack (837 bytes)

Congrats, el-get is installed and ready to serve!nil
```

Thanks to these two posts - very helpful.

https://github.com/dimitri/el-get/issues/220

[enter link description here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27326/gui-emacs-sets-the-exec-path-only-from-windows-environment-variable-but-not-from)